# Unable to activate sendmail due to error

Tags: linux, sendmail, fedora-21

I installed sendmail on my Fedora 21 Server installation but when I start it and check it's status I get the following:

```
[root@localhost mail]# systemctl status sendmail
● sendmail.service - Sendmail Mail Transport Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sendmail.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: resources) since Thu 2015-06-04 11:23:31 CEST; 2min 39s ago
  Process: 31776 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sendmail -bd $SENDMAIL_OPTS $SENDMAIL_OPTARG (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 31766 ExecStartPre=/etc/mail/make aliases (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 31763 ExecStartPre=/etc/mail/make (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 04 11:23:31 localhost.localdomain sendmail[31776]: -bd is not supported by sSMTP
Jun 04 11:23:31 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Sendmail Mail Transport Agent.
Jun 04 11:23:31 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit sendmail.service entered failed state.
Jun 04 11:23:31 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: sendmail.service failed.
```

What is the problem here? I thought the `-bd is not supported by sSMTP` was a hint. But I can't find anything on this either.

Answer (score 3):

sSMTP is a send-only sendmail emulator. It does not support -bd option when run as a daemon (see "man ssmtp"). Current sendmail in F21 is an alias to ssmtp. You need to remove ssmtp entirely from F21 (yum erase sSMTP).